# How to prevent Jackson from serializing the response from a controller method in Spring MVC based REST API?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I am developing an **Angular 2** app that requires to serve a file by making a request for a file at the **backend**.

I am returning the requested file's File object from the backend. But the **Jackson** is serializing that response automatically, and I am getting file name as a response rather than a file as a whole.

Moreover the file is an XML file. Could anyone help as to how to prevent Jackson from serializing the Java File object that my controller method is sending?

---

#### EDIT

Added the controller code that does file serving

```
@RequestMapping(value = FatcaConstants.GET_XML_FILE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public File getXML(@RequestParam(value = "filePath") String filePath) {
    LOG.info("Getting the XML report from the file path in the Controller");
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.info("Error in retrieving file " + filePath + " from the FileController");
        LOG.info(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the Content-Type of reponse, maybe Jackson serialize all that is `application/xml`.

Comment: Read the documentation and understand what you may return from a Spring MVC method. Returning a File is not the appropriate way of returning the content of the file in the response. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-return-types and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-message-conversion

Comment: I am new to all this, will look into the docs to figure something out. On a side note, is there really a way to prevent a method's return object from getting serialized by the jackson?

Comment: I'm not sure that using a REST controller to serve a static content is the right approach (though it is doable). A better approach will be to map the file as a `resource` (google it or read this post: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources)

Comment: What have you given in your `produces` property of REST endpoint? Show your endpoint code as well please

Comment: I just realized that this is not the way to do, I was misled. Is there a way to send the file via jackson?

Comment: Actually, I figured out a workaround for the problem. I am sending the xml data from the backend as an attribute of a json object and using that data to create an xml file at the frontend via filesaverjs